# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException while calling Database name (for calling stored procedure in it)

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I have made a stored procedure for user Login with two parameters 1)Username and 2)Password. After enter User name and Password in the text field and hitting Login button I am facing this issue.

I have also enabled IIS from 'Windows Features Turn On and OFF' but it didn't work.

Someone please help me out.

[image: Here is the code]

Comment: Member for 2 years should generally know its best to post code as _text_ rather than an image.  It promotes better searchability. [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: You are not connected to the database specified.  Make sure the entity name for the connection is vezaDB.

Comment: @jdweng I am giving absolutely right connection name

Comment: Are you connecting remotely or locally?  IIS you have limited access to the file system.   Post connection string.

Comment: @jdweng Locally, if it have limited access to IIS then how to resolve it ?

Comment: I need to see the connection string.  Different versions of the connection string will require different fixes.